# When calling FB.ui to publish a feed, it would show "Require Captcha"

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, feed

When our app's published feed use fb.ui, the page would show "require captcha". We test the feed data, and found that if we use our CDN provider url like

> http://upupgame.sslcs.cdngc.net/client/images/msi/t08.png

The required captcha would show. If change we changed it to another URL which doesn't even exist, it would show the fb.ui.

Has our CDN URL has been banned? How to resolve it? We checked our insights and not found other any warning. Our data stat shows as healthy!

Comment: is all fb developers in vacation?

Comment: Running into this issue with AWS Cloudfront as well.